# Display image from db info

Tags: php, html

First I am an amateur in coding, everything I have done so far is trail and error. I am trying to produce a table that exports information to a web page. So far all works fine except I can not figure out how to get the images to show. It will only show the http of where the image is stored. I would also like this image to be displayed as a thumbnail that can open in a light box full size when clicked on.
This will be 30 or more lines in the table.

My current coding is:

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<th>Team Name</th><th>Team Captian</th><th>Total Damage</th><th>Best 1</th><th>Best 2</th><th>Best 3</th><th>Best 4</th><th>Best 5</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user2_pvedama";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "user2_pvedamage";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, fullname, damage, FILEUPLOAD1, FILEUPLOAD2, FILEUPLOAD3, FILEUPLOAD4, FILEUPLOAD5  FROM tdamage"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have searched the site but have found nothing that I could use (as far as I can figure)

So Changed this part but I am still getting errors?

```
$a = "FILEUPLOAD1";
$b = "FILEUPLOAD2";
$c = "FILEUPLOAD3";
$d = "FILEUPLOAD4";
$e = "FILEUPLOAD5";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, fullname, damage, echo '<img src="' . $a . '">';, echo '<img src="' . $b . '">';, echo '<img src="' . $c . '">';, echo '<img src="' . $d . '">';, echo '<img src="' . $e . '">';  FROM tdamage"); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Updated to:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, fullname, damage, FILEUPLOAD1, FILEUPLOAD2, FILEUPLOAD3, FILEUPLOAD4, FILEUPLOAD5  FROM tdamage"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v; if (strstr($k, 'FILEUPLOAD1')) { echo '<img src="' . $v . '">'; }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Current updated code:

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<th>Team Name</th><th>Team Captian</th><th>Total Damage</th><th>Best 1</th><th>Best 2</th><th>Best 3</th><th>Best 4</th><th>Best 5</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user2_pvedama";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "user2_pvedamage";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, fullname, damage, FILEUPLOAD1, FILEUPLOAD2, FILEUPLOAD3, FILEUPLOAD4, FILEUPLOAD5  FROM tdamage"); 
    $stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    if (strstr($k, 'FILEUPLOAD')) { 
        echo '<img src="' . $v . '">'; 
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried that and get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FILEUPLOAD1' (T_STRING)      I made it <img scr="FILEUPLOAD1">         I hope thats what you meant, I am a noob please bear with me

Comment: So in part I changed ("SELECT username, fullname, damage, FILEUPLOAD1,   to   ("SELECT username, fullname, damage, echo '<img src="' . $FILEUPLOAD1 . '">';,    that gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' . $FILEUPLOAD1 . '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)    I can see what your showing me and why, I just don't know how it gets installed

Comment: OK, I am getting closer now, I added that after the echo $v; and got the image placeholder to show up, but not the image. Also did not show in the table but on top of the table and the http info was still in the table.